# FacebookApiException: SSL connection timeout , in web application not facebook app

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

im working on localhost.
im trying to execute this api :

```
$user_albums_photos = $facebook->api(array(
            'method'    => 'fql.query',
            'query'     => 'SELECT src,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())'
     ));

     print_r($user_albums_photos);
     $r_c = count($user_albums_photos);
     echo "<br>$r_c<br>";
```

but im getting this exception :

```
FacebookApiException: SSL connection timeout in F:\Apache2.2\htdocs\FriendLooks\extlib\base_facebook.php on line 820 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0021342048{main}( )..\freindsloog_fb_galery.php:0 20.0155633832BaseFacebook->api( )..\freindsloog_fb_galery.php:103 30.0155634232BaseFacebook->_restserver( )..\base_facebook.php:551 40.0157639040BaseFacebook->_oauthRequest( )..\base_facebook.php:705 50.0157639040BaseFacebook->getAccessToken( )..\base_facebook.php:761 60.0157639136BaseFacebook->getUserAccessToken( )..\base_facebook.php:317 70.0160639784BaseFacebook->getAccessTokenFromCode( )..\base_facebook.php:351 80.0161640216BaseFacebook->_oauthRequest( )..\base_facebook.php:669 90.0162640672BaseFacebook->makeRequest( )..\base_facebook.php:771 Variables in local scope (#9)

$CURL_OPTS =

Undefined

$ch =

resource(7, Unknown)

$e =

object(FacebookApiException)[2]
  protected 'result' => 
    array
      'error_code' => int 28
      'error' => 
        array
          'message' => string 'SSL connection timeout' (length=22)
          'type' => string 'CurlException' (length=13)
  protected 'message' => string 'SSL connection timeout' (length=22)
  private 'string' (Exception) => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'code' => int 28
  protected 'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
  protected 'line' => int 820
  private 'trace' (Exception) => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 771
          'function' => string 'makeRequest' (length=11)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      1 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 669
          'function' => string '_oauthRequest' (length=13)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      2 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 351
          'function' => string 'getAccessTokenFromCode' (length=22)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      3 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 317
          'function' => string 'getUserAccessToken' (length=18)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      4 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 761
          'function' => string 'getAccessToken' (length=14)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      5 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 705
          'function' => string '_oauthRequest' (length=13)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      6 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'extlib\base_facebook.php' (length=56)
          'line' => int 551
          'function' => string '_restserver' (length=11)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
      7 => 
        array
          'file' => string 'freindsloog_fb_galery.php' (length=57)
          'line' => int 103
          'function' => string 'api' (length=3)
          'class' => string 'BaseFacebook' (length=12)
          'type' => string '->' (length=2)
          'args' => 
            array
              ...
  private 'previous' (Exception) => null

$existing_headers =

Undefined

$opts =

array
  78 => int 10
  19913 => int 1
  13 => int 60
  10018 => string 'facebook-php-3.1' (length=16)
  10015 => string 'client_id=309069922463681&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=&code=2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.3600.1328119200.1-557002013%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&access_token=309069922463681%7Cxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=232)
  10002 => string 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token' (length=45)
  10023 => 
    array
      0 => string 'Expect:' (length=7)

$params =

array
  'client_id' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=15)
  'client_secret' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=32)
  'redirect_uri' => string '' (length=0)
  'code' => string '2.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.3600.1328119200.1-557002013|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=74)
  'access_token' => string 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (length=48)

$result =

boolean false

$url =

string 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token' (length=45)

Array ( )
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're attempting to use an APP access token when you should be using a USER access token. I could tell your access token was an APP because is has the | pipe in it.